# Strange lag in http pipeline with ASP.NET MVC on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on IIS6 with enabled wildcard mapping. After performing some load tests I digged into log files with focus on the slow requests. I have a log file from the load testing application, IIS log file and the log file from the [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) I develop for this purpose which records time of [`Application.BeginRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) and [`Application.EndRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest.aspx).

When I compared data for slow requests in the IIS log file and the log file of my module I've discovered some odd behavior.

```
var request_processing_start = iis_log_file.time - iis_log_file.taken
var aspnet_processing_start = my_module_log_file.begin_request_called
var aspnet_processing_end = my_module_log_file.end_request_called
var request_processing_end = iis_log_file.time
```

For all requests values of `aspnet_processing_end` and `request_processing_end` match pretty close (difference no more then few milliseconds). However some requests have timespan between `request_processing_start` and `aspnet_processing_start` up to 30 seconds. **What is the cause of this lag and a how can I prevent it?**

---

Some more details of load test I've done:

- **Number of requests:** on long time average 2 per seconds, in the peaks no more then 20 per second. (This is really low, we cannot blame wildcard mapping)
- **Processor usage:** flat line bellow 5% (We cannot blame lack of cpu power)
- **Free memory:** more than 1GB (Memory isn't also issue).
- The lag I described is occurring only when the server is under load. When the load testing application isn't running it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I am having a similar problem in an application I am working on. The platform for my application is IIS 7.5, ASP.NET 4.0, ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and Entity Framework 4.0.

Comment: @Dhwanil: We didn't. However we optimized several bottlenecks and we haven't been facing this problem recently. My guess is that the requests been waiting in ASP.NET request queue. Try to play with `processModel/maxworkerthreads` and also if your app is calling any external web services with `connectionManagement/maxconnection`.